# DRF - 'ServersSerializer' object has no attribute 'attr_name' - calling external SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to abstract out a SerializerMethodField with no success.

This is what I currently have in my serializers.py

```
class ServersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bmccode = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_bmc')

    def get_bmc(self, obj):
        code = Tblbmcgroups.objects.filter(groupid = obj.recordownerid).values_list('bmccode')[0][0]
        return code

    app_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_app')

    def get_app(self, obj):
        code = Tblapplicationserverlinks.objects.filter(serverid=obj.id).values_list(
            'applicationid__name', flat=True).distinct()
        return code

    class Meta:
        model = Servers
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'isvirtual', 'locationid', 'managedbyid', 'operatingsystem', 'model',
                  'assettag', 'inceptiondate', 'comments', 'assetstatusid', 'recordownerid', 'lastmodifieddate',
                  'lastmodifiedby', 'app_name', 'bmccode')
        depth = 1
```

The above works, but what I want is to have a scripts/joining_data.py file which contains the following -

```
    def get_bmc(self, obj):
        code = Tblbmcgroups.objects.filter(groupid = obj.recordownerid).values_list('bmccode')[0][0]
        return code
```

This way the code can be used by other serializers.  The problem is by doing this in my serializers.py

```
class ServersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bmccode = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_bmc')

    app_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_app')

    def get_app(self, obj):
        code = Tblapplicationserverlinks.objects.filter(serverid=obj.id).values_list(
            'applicationid__name', flat=True).distinct()
        return code

    class Meta:
        model = Servers
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'isvirtual', 'locationid', 'managedbyid', 'operatingsystem', 'model',
                  'assettag', 'inceptiondate', 'comments', 'assetstatusid', 'recordownerid', 'lastmodifieddate',
                  'lastmodifiedby', 'app_name', 'bmccode')
        depth = 1
```

It's not recognizing the attribute that's no longer in the serializer.

I'm doing an `from scripts.joining_data import *`

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in view
  87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  45.             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  674.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  239.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  614.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  472.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in to_representation
  1642.         method = getattr(self.parent, self.method_name)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/servers/
Exception Value: 'ServersSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_bmc'
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: should your bmccode field have `'get_bmc'` as string? `bmccode = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_bmc')`.

Comment: yeah it should.  doing that however returns `'ServersSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_bmc'`  I'll update the question.

Comment: I think you don't have the function `get_bmc` in your class anymore. Did you delete it by accident?

Comment: @ShangWang I've updated the question.  The get_bmc I'm trying to abstract out as it's re-usable by other serializers I don't want to keep copy/pasting the code.

Comment: But it should belong to the class isn't it? I've never used DRF but sounds like the class instance will call the instance function later on. You should always define 'get_app', but you can let `get_app` call the function you abstracted out.

Comment: How would I do that then?  I tried `get_bmc = get_bmc(self=self, obj=obj)` and it just complains that self/obj don't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mixin pattern. Something like this:

```
class BMCMixin(object):
    bmccode = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_bmc')
    def get_bmc(self, obj):
        code = Tblbmcgroups.objects.filter(groupid=obj.recordownerid).values_list('bmccode')[0][0]
        return code


class ServersSerializer(BMCMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
   ... servers specific code ...
```

You can put mixin classes into a separate file and import them at your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

`get_bmc` should belong to the class. your extracted function shouldn't take `self` argument, because it doesn't belong to any class.

Honestly I don't think extracting a one-liner would save you any time, but for the sake of correctness, here's what you should do:

```
def external_get_bmc(obj):
    return Tblapplicationserverlinks.objects.filter(serverid=obj.id) \
                                            .values_list('applicationid__name', 
                                                         flat=True) \
                                            .distinct()

class ServersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_bmc(self, obj):
        return external_get_bmc(obj)
```

If you really want to only define it once, consider using [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for the mention of inheritance.  I wasn't thinking about that and looks like what I need to do.

Comment: Yep. Make a mixin class with all the functions you need and add it as a base class to the serializers you need to have these features.